# How does a lambda that captures a shared_ptr by value affect its use_count()?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, shared-ptr

I am curious about the lifespan of a shared_ptr when captured by value within a lambda.

I had expected its `use_count()` to always be >= 1 as long as the lambda is still in memory, but my test shows something unexpected: use count falls to 0, then increments to 1 inside the lambda body...

Here's what I tested:

1. create a shared_ptr
2. define a lambda that captures the shared_ptr by value
3. reset the shared_ptr
4. run the lambda

At stage 3, the shared_ptr's `use_count()` falls to 0 - but the object is not destroyed.  At stage 4 - inside the lambda - `use_count()` is back to 1.  After the lambda is run, `use_count()` goes back to 0, but the object is not destroyed until the lambda is destroyed.

I'm wondering how / why this could be?

Shouldn't `use_count()` be 2 after the lambda definition and then 1 inside the lambda?

---

[testing code on Repl.it:](https://repl.it/repls/SkeletalOrderlyGraphics)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo {
public:
  Foo( int v = 0 ) : val(v) {}
  ~Foo(){
    std::cout << "--- Foo destroyed ---" << std::endl;
  }
  int val = 0;
};

void logPtr( const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& p ){
    std::cout << "ptr: refs = " << p.use_count();
    if (p) {
      std::cout << ", val = " << p->val << std::endl;
    }
    else {
     std::cout << ", nullptr" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {

  std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = std::make_shared<Foo>( 0 );

  logPtr(ptr);

  std::cout << "--- define lambda ---\n";

  auto lambda = [=]() {

    std::cout << "--- run lambda ---\n";
    if (ptr) { ptr->val++; }
    logPtr(ptr);
    std::cout << "--- end lambda ---\n";

  };

  logPtr(ptr);

  std::cout << "--- reset ptr ---\n";
  ptr.reset();
  logPtr(ptr);

  // run lambda
  lambda();
  logPtr(ptr);

}
```

---

here is the output:

```
ptr: refs = 1, val = 0
--- define lambda ---
ptr: refs = 2, val = 0
--- reset ptr ---
ptr: refs = 0, nullptr
--- run lambda ---
ptr: refs = 1, val = 1
--- end lambda ---
ptr: refs = 0, nullptr
--- Foo destroyed ---
```

Comment: Nothing to do with lambdas. Here's the same code without using a lambda: https://repl.it/repls/LonelyDishonestBetaversion.

Comment: Once you clear the shared_ptr object, you can't get the object's use count any more... because there's no object (and no shared_counter) being pointed to any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't `use_count()` be 2 after the lambda definition

It is:

> ```
> --- define lambda ---
> ptr: refs = 2, val = 0
> ```

> and then 1 inside the lambda?

It is:

> ```
> --- run lambda ---
> ptr: refs = 1, val = 1
> ```

The part you're confused about has nothing to do with lambdas. You can produce the same effect by creating a simple copy of the shared pointer:

```
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = std::make_shared<Foo>( 0 );

  logPtr( ptr );

  std::cout << "--- define lambda ---\n";

  auto cpy = ptr;

  logPtr(ptr);

  std::cout << "--- reset ptr ---\n";    
  ptr.reset();

  logPtr(ptr);

  // run "lambda"   
  {
    std::cout << "--- run lambda ---\n";
    if (cpy) {
      cpy->val++;
    }
    logPtr( cpy );
    std::cout << "--- end lambda ---\n";    
  }

  logPtr( ptr );
```

What you seem to be missing is the semantics of `reset()`. As [cppreference explains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset), it

> Releases the ownership of the managed object, if any.

Which means

> If `*this` already owns an object and *it is the last `shared_ptr` owning it*, the object is destroyed through the owned deleter.

In your code there are initially two shared pointers, sharing ownership of the referenced object.

After `ptr.reset()`, the first pointer stops being an owner. It is reset back to `null` / `0`. However, the second pointer (the copy inside the lambda) still is an owner and keeps the referenced object alive (now with a `use_count` of 1).

The rest of your code simply examines two different pointers: One still owning the object, and the other not owning anything.

The equivalent code using raw pointers would look like this:

```
Foo *ptr = new Foo(0);
Foo *cpy = ptr;  // create a copy
ptr = null;      // "reset" the first pointer
logPtr(cpy);     // examine the copy
delete cpy;      // release the object through the last active pointer
```

Comment: Thanks!  That makes perfect sense.  I'm not sure why I thought I could retain access to the original pointer / use_count() after calling reset().  Pretty silly in hindsight.

Comment: I am confused though why use_count should increase after lambda definition, since my understanding is lambda is just syntactic sugar over regular functions so why use_count is increased after definition it should be only after function/lambda call.

Comment: @Kapil "*since my understanding is lambda is just syntactic sugar over regular functions*" - when capturing is involved, a lambda is more like a functor (a struct/class with an `operator()` defined) instead of a plain function. In this case, captured values are implicit members of the functor that the compiler generates to implement the lambda. So it makes sense that the `use_count` would increase when the lambda is created and make a copy of the `shared_ptr` into itself.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for the explanation, I got it now why use_count is incremented after lamda definition